# Crash in Dynamic Code Evolution VM

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I am trying to run a Swing Client using [Dynamic Code Evolution VM](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) in IntelliJ  using [DCEVM](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/07/get-true-hot-swap-in-java-with-dcevm-and-intellij-idea/) integration plugin.When I start the app it crashes with following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no freetype in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary$1.run(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:59)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary.<clinit>(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:32)
And
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.font.SunFontManager
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:264)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1012)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1624)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.getPreferredSize(SynthGraphicsUtils.java:283)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.getMinimumSize(SynthGraphicsUtils.java:195)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthButtonUI.getMinimumSize(SynthButtonUI.java:461)
```

I verified that SunFontManager is exist in rt.jar. Any idea?

Comment: I know this question is old but i'm having the same problem... When I switch to another VM the error is gone but I like to be able to Hot Swap :( How did you fix it, or did you also use another VM?

Comment: I couldn't find any solution for this problem. But now I am using http://www.hotswapagent.org/. It is based on DCEVM. Working perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

DCEVM does not ship with fonts. So, when the JVM tries to load up the fonts, it doesn't find any and crashes. Fortunately, the fix is very easy. Simply copy the fonts from another JDK/JRE. You will find them at /jre/lib/fonts. Copy the entire directory to /lib.

Comment: Hi Peter.. Could you please take a look at my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67411758/unable-to-launch-sas-deployment-manager-no-freetype-in-java-library-path). I believe it is a similar problem, but I tried your solution with no luck. Thanks!